# Windows command line tilde operators for full environment variables?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

In cmd, you can use the tilde "operator" to do some cool tricks with arguments passed in. For example, %~dp0 returns the pathname of the current script.

Can you do that for any environment variable? For example:

```
 set foo=1234.exe
 echo %~nfoo%
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: `help set` and `help for` will show you all possible usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also filter your variable through a `for` loop instead of a subroutine:

```
setlocal
set foo=1234.exe
for %%I in ("%foo%") do echo %%~nI
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of.

In the following file (I named test1.cmd) there is an example of passing a file path and name to a subroutine in the same .cmd file and getting the drive letter and path back.  By setting more environment variables on the last line of the subroutine you could return more combinations of drive letter, path, file name, attributes, etc.

That last line is the important part.  The Windows command processor evaluates a line at a time, so that line first expands environment variables to their text values and then proccesses the line.  That expanded line destroys the scope of the subroutine, returning to the outer scope (endlocal), sets a new variable (mytest2) to the value of the subroutine's (expanded) %dp1, then executes a goto :eof, which returns to the calling line.

```
setlocal

set mytest=c:\windows\a file with spaces in name.txt

call :mytest2 "%mytest%"

echo %mytest2%

:ender
endlocal

goto :eof

:mytest2
setlocal
echo %~dp1

endlocal && set mytest2=%~dp1 && goto :eof
```